# Using groupby but not creating series

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes
train_family_sales

```
    family  store_nbr   date    unit_sales
0   GROCERY I   1.0 2016-08-01  3.0
1   GROCERY I   1.0 2016-08-02  10.0
2   GROCERY I   1.0 2016-08-04  3.0
3   AUTOMOTIVE  1.0 2016-08-05  5.0
4   AUTOMOTIVE  1.0 2016-08-06  5.0
```

and train_sales

```
    date       store_nbr item_nbr unit_sales    family  
0   2016-08-01 1.0       103520   3.0         GROCERY I     
1   2016-08-02 1.0       103520   1.0         GROCERY I     
2   2016-08-04 1.0       103520   6.0         GROCERY I 
3   2016-08-05 1.0       103520   2.0         AUTOMOTIVE        
4   2016-08-06 1.0       103520   2.0         AUTOMOTIVE
```

I would like to merge them where I get the following

```
    date       store_nbr item_nbr unit_sales    family    f_unit_sales
0   2016-08-01 1.0       103520   3.0         GROCERY I     3.0
1   2016-08-02 1.0       103520   1.0         GROCERY I     10.0
2   2016-08-04 1.0       103520   3.0         GROCERY I     3.0
3   2016-08-05 1.0       103520   2.0         AUTOMOTIVE    5.0 
4   2016-08-06 1.0       103520   2.0         AUTOMOTIVE    6.0
```

Im trying to do this doing the following:

```
both_sales = train_sales_with_family.join(train_family_sales,how='left', on=['store_nbr','family','date'], rsuffix='f_')
```

But I get an error.
ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

Any suggestions on how to do this merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
both_sales = train_sales.merge(train_family_sales,
                               how='left',
                               on=['store_nbr','family','date'],
                               suffixes=('','_'))
```

Or add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `join` - need same levels of `MultiIndex` as columns in `on` parameter:

```
both_sales = train_sales.join(train_family_sales.set_index(['store_nbr','family','date']), 
                               on=['store_nbr','family','date'], 
                               rsuffix='_')
```

---

```
print (both_sales)

         date  store_nbr  item_nbr  unit_sales      family unit_sales_
0  2016-08-01        1.0    103520         3.0   GROCERY I          3.0
1  2016-08-02        1.0    103520         1.0   GROCERY I         10.0
2  2016-08-04        1.0    103520         6.0   GROCERY I          3.0
3  2016-08-05        1.0    103520         2.0  AUTOMOTIVE          5.0
4  2016-08-06        1.0    103520         2.0  AUTOMOTIVE          5.0
```

Comment: Maybe we can use set_index and map here. This solution looks better